# ngx-translate : Cannot read property 'currentLang' of undefined

Tags: angular, git, angular6, ngx-translate

I'm working on an Angular 6 project, and I'm facing a pretty annoying problem since I merged a feature branch.

To make it simple :

- We are using the `ngx-translate` module from the beginning of the project, and it worked fine until now
- We are creating features (like the one I merged) on git branches, and we merge them on the develop branch when we finished
- Both develop and feature branches worked before the merge

Now, after merging, I'm getting the following error on the `ngx-translate` module when the app bootstraps :
[image: ngx-translate error]

(Another copy of the stack trace)

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentLang' of undefined
    at TranslationService.get currentLang [as currentLang] (ngx-translate-core.js:398)
    at TranslationService.use (ngx-translate-core.js:489)
    at new AppComponent (app.component.ts:29)
    at createClass (core.js:11733)
    at createDirectiveInstance (core.js:11554)
    at createViewNodes (core.js:13095)
    at createRootView (core.js:12967)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:14455)
    at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView] (core.js:13702)
    at ComponentFactory_.create (core.js:10705)`

After a day of searching, I still can't figure out why this error has appeared. What is strange is that none of the code that produces the error has been edited (neither on the develop or feature branch).

I can tell that this error happens after a call of `translateService.use('en')` (we can see it on the stack trace), and the reason is that the `TranslateService` isn't instantiated correctly on app bootstrap.

Here is a breakpoint when the constructor of the `TranslateService` is called, and we can see that most of the parameters are `undefined` : [image: Breakpoint 1]

Here is the same breakpoint, but with a functional version of the project (before merging, so), and there is no `undefined` parameter : [image: Breakpoint 3]

So if anyone has any idea of what's going on, it would be a HUGE help, because I'm out of fresh ideas!

Edit - Here is my the code of my `AppComponent`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { LangService } from './core/services/lang.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(
    private translate: TranslateService,
    private languageService: LanguageService,
  ) {
    this.translate.use('fr');
    const subLang = this.languageService.getLangs().subscribe((rep) => {
      this.translate.addLangues(rep);
      this.translate.setDefaultLang(rep.find((l) => l.defaut).code);
      this.translate.use(localStorage.getItem('lang'));
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: you can check the "diff" with the previous commit before the merge where the issue is occurring if it was working fine in the develop branch before.Most likely there is a version mismatch between your branches

Comment: Can you please show us the code from `AppComponent`?

Comment: @Niladri I'll do a check on modules versions right now, I'll keep you in touch.
@user184994 I edited my post to add the code of the `AppComponent` but I don't think it will help more since this code hasn't been modified for a long time.

Comment: @Niladri So i did some checks but it doesn't seems to be a version mismatch (or perhaps a strange behavior with the `yarn.lock`). I did the following test that is, to me, relevant : I `git checkout` on a old functionnal version (and test it, so it works !), then I `git checkout` on the last version (so the `node_module` isn't changed at all) and then the app breaks.

Answer (score -1):

Ok so I finally figured out what was happening.

It was simply the `tsconfig.json` that has been edited in my feature branch.

So this here is the part :

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    ...
    "target": "es6" <------- This is the part that is failing
  }
}
```

When I used Angular CLI to create the app, this line was set to `"target": "es5"` but I changed it to `es6` in my feature branch for whatever reason, and before merging all was working just fine.

It's after merging that the bug appeared... and I still don't know why !

So I just switched back to `"target": "es5"` and now it is working.

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score -1):

in app.component.ts in constructor file

```
  constructor(public translation: TranslateService) {
    translattion.addLangs(['en', 'ur', 'sd']);
    translattion.setDefaultLang('en');
  }
```

make sure to import the library on top of you app.component.ts

```
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
```

and now in any ts file in your project just call the above library and initialize it in the constructor

otherServices.service.ts file

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient, private translation: TranslateService) { 

    this.translation.use(this.translation.getBrowserLang());
    console.log(this.translattion.currentLang)
    //outpu is en . en is the default language
  }
```